# show module value in template laravel

Tags: laravel, get, field

I am new to Laravel I have install laravel 5.2 and running laraadmin.
I have added a 'header' module with field phone and want to show it in my blade template on my site.
Please help me. 
 my controller name headercontroller have the code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Class HomeController
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
class headerController extends Controller
{

     public function index()
    {

        $header = headers::all();
        return view('layout.aap')->with('headers', $header);

    }
}
```

my view file name is "app.blade.php" inside a folder name "layout" have the following code

```
{{ $header -> phone }}
```

I cannot show the phone number on site please help me.

Comment: Laravel 5.2 is oldest version. Update your laravel 5.2 to laravel 6. To update use ```composer update```. Now coming to your point, if you would like display a phone number or any field which is coming from database, then you have to pass it from controller.

Comment: laravel 6 is not working with laraadmin

Comment: How I can pass it from controller

Answer (score 0):

I didn't worked on laraadmin. But you can try this -

In your controller -

```
public function example(){
 $data = Phone::all(); //Phone is model name. You make change according to your's
 return view('xyz', compact('data'));
}
```

Now in your view you can access variable data.

```
@foreach($data as $d)
 <span>$d->phone</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: aap.blade is my template name so xyz will replace with what value ?

Comment: with ```aap.blade.php```

Comment: try above foreach ```{{dd($data)}}``` and let me know value..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205842/discussion-between-abhishek-honrao-and-sultan).

Comment: should i include all path of view file or only name will work?